# AG of 2 replicas on 2 nodes in WSFC : is it possible to add 3rd replica to AG and NOT add 3rd machine WSFC?

Tags: availability-groups, clustering, sql-server-2017

Please help to to research the possibility of below:

We have availability group that consists of two replicas:

```
replica 1: SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016
replica 2: SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016
```

Both machines are part of one Windows Server Failover Cluster

Is it possible to add a 3rd replica (SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016) to existing availability group, without adding a 3rd machine to existing WSFC ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this? You could join the replica to the WSFC and not give it a vote in the WSFC. There are "Read-scale availability groups" or clusterless AG's, but they are AG based, not replica based.

Comment: Reason is sysadmin is very reluctant of adding 3rd node to WSFC. However vote without a node might be a good option. Is not a direct answer to this question, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a 3rd replica (SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2016) to existing availability group, without adding a 3rd machine to existing WSFC ?

No, there are explicit checks to see if the node of an AG is already hosting the same AG. If you want a 3rd replica, add a 3rd note.

I'd also advise against stacking up on multiple instances of SQL Server on the same machine, simply for administrative and troubleshooting purposes.